# Extract DataFrame from a list of indices of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I've a DataFrame "A" and a list of indices "I". I want to generate/get a DataFrame "B" which contains only the data in those indices "I" of the original DataFrame "A". How can I achieve this?

Assuming `I = [1, 3]` , I tried this `A.filter(items=I, axis=0)` is this the right way, or is there an even better way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think to need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d'],
    'B': list(range(9))
})
print (A)
   A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1
2  a  2
3  a  3
4  b  4
5  b  5
6  b  6
7  c  7

I = [1,3]
B = A.loc[I]
print (B)
   A  B
1  a  1
3  a  3
```